# Primefaces 5.0: calendar not hide after select

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar, themes

I'm using calendar component with Primefaces 5.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" 
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

<h:body id="body">

<h:form id="frm">

    <p:outputLabel value="My Date:" />

    <p:calendar value="#{mybean.myDate}" 
            pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"  
            id="myDate" 
            >
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"/>
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="@this" event="dateSelect"/>
    </p:calendar>                             

</h:form>    

</h:body>

</html>
```

My web.xml is set as:

```
<context-param>                          
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>    
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>     
</context-param>
```

This component works fine, but has an anomaly: when user select a date without set a time then calendar does not hide, otherwise when user select a date and after a time then calendar hides.

Can I set my calendar component to hide after date select?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by changing calendar pattern:

```
pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Look at PrimeFaces ShowCase [PF Calendar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml).

Comment: So you want that user select a date and time is then set automatically?

Comment: I want that if user select date or time then calendar component hides automatically. Now calendar component remains opened also after selected...

Comment: I think you can do that by using onblur or onselect attribute and then manually close calendar.